# Semi-colon when defining a rule

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I'm reading a simple line of Prolog code:

```
sibling(X, Y) :- brother(X, Y); sister(X, Y).
```

I know if it was:

```
sibling(X, Y) :- brother(X, Y), sister(X, Y).
```

then that would mean the brother(X, Y) AND sister(X, Y) must be true for sibling(X, Y) to be true. This makes me believe that ";" represents the or operator so would:

```
sibling(X, Y) :- brother(X, Y); sister(X, Y).
```

evaluate to true if brother(X, Y) OR sister(X, Y) is true?

Comment: Yes, `;` basically means OR.

Answer (score 3):

As lurker remarked, `;/2` is Prolog goal disjunction control construct. Btw, Prolog coding guidelines advice against clauses such as:

```
sibling(X, Y) :- brother(X, Y); sister(X, Y).
```

The suggested alternative is:

```
sibling(X, Y) :- brother(X, Y).
sibling(X, Y) :- sister(X, Y).
```

But if you do use a disjunction in the body of a clause, always write it between parenthesis. In this case:

```
sibling(X, Y) :-
    (   brother(X, Y)
    ;   sister(X, Y)
    ).
```

Comment: @tas Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

, is and (which is conjunction) 
; is or (which is disjunction)